# How can I make a proper facebook payment in unity3d webGL?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make unity webgl game. I'm currently working with my own python django server. But there's few problems I am confronting right now.

First, when client completes the payment behavior, it repeatedly shows javascript error. Here's the error code:

```
Invoking error handler due to
Uncaught abort(219) at Error
at jsStackTrace (lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:22313)
at stackTrace [Object.stackTrace] (lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:22484)
at Object.onAbort (https:/lottery-server.ntucorp.com/static/game/Build/UnityLoader.js:4:11047)
at abort ('lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:521824')
at wasm-function[62206]:0x1143303
at wasm-function[25973]:0x9c45e6
at wasm-function[61403]:0x111d42f
at wasm-function[27992]:0xa2a9df
at wasm-function[50781]:0xeabcd7
at wasm-function[35699]:0xba8a56
at wasm-function[35698]:0xba8997
at wasm-function[35744]:0xbaa780
at wasm-function[26171]:0x9c9232
at wasm-function[35758]:0xbab0e3
at wasm-function[26171]:0x9c9232
at wasm-function[35768]:0xbab37e
at wasm-function[23663]:0x9815d2
at wasm-function[61943]:0x11424be
at dynCall_iiiii [Object.dynCall_iiiii] (lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:494571)
at invoke_iiiii (lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:362010)
at wasm-function[59810]:0x10db82f
at wasm-function[59101]:0x10b9e40
at wasm-function[4047]:0x197f91
at wasm-function[4046]:0x197ebf
at wasm-function[7537]:0x2c346b
at wasm-function[7534]:0x2c283b
at wasm-function[11356]:0x483dc2
at wasm-function[9973]:0x3cab31
at blob:https:/lottery-server.ntucorp.com/d6308b13-98d3-4a85-abfd-0c7db365fcfd:8:438788
at ccall [Object.ccall] (lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:16382)
at SendMessage (lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:9099)
at sendMessage [Object.sendMessage] (lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:48724)
at uiCallback (lottery.wasm.framework.unityweb:8:50342)
at a.__wrapper.a.__wrapper (https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:93:765)
at Object.cb (https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:145:4420)
at c (https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:145:10332)
at a.c.read (https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:125:737)
at a._processor (https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:127:283)
at a.b.enqueue (https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:126:711)
at Object.u [as onMessage] (https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:143:2477)
at https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:136:2925
at https:/connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=11641b2e4a5fab828e74fff5f206cf37&ua=modern_es6:50:208'''
```

I'm using Unity Facebook SDK, so in unity c# script I call this function.

```
FB.Canvas.Pay(
product_url,
quantity:1,
callback:ProductCallback
);
```

And, anyway it gives callback function back, and the response of this callback is this.

```
PayResponse:{"callback_id":"4","response":{"payment_id":1794879660642720,"amount":"2.99","currency":"USD","quantity":"1","request_id":"","status":"initiated","signed_request":"r4_00GLFbodYSMVeVGfFcfuzIr1HQKd9EYiO_OM0eXM.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImFtb3VudCI6IjIuOTkiLCJjdXJyZW5jeSI6IlVTRCIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTU3ODA0MzI2OCwicGF5bWVudF9pZCI6MTc5NDg3OTY2MDY0MjcyMCwicXVhbnRpdHkiOiIxIiwicmVxdWVzdF9pZCI6IiIsInN0YXR1cyI6ImluaXRpYXRlZCJ9"}}
```

And secondly I cannot make Facebook Unity SDK workable, which is FB.Canvas.PayWithProductID. It just don't work, It just omits javascript error (UnityLoader.js error which is similar to one which I already mentioned), and also it do not give callback.

Also In document, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games_payments/payments_lite?locale=ko_KR In here it says proper code would be FB.PayWithProductID, but Facebook SDK does not have any FB.PayWithProductID. All it have is FB**.Canvas.**PayWithProductID.

How can I get proper callback from facebook?  I cannot get any kind of callback parameters. All I recieve is that the fact facebook called my callback url, not containing any GET parameters. I just return request.GET.get('hub.challenge'), but anyway it is still None.

Why does it happen? please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question as it includes so much into this. I would recommend connecting your project to API and then call Facebooks API to take payments. Here is the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/payment

I am only saying this because there is not a lot of context here as to how and where you're calling the payment method from. Are you already doing this from an API? or are you trying achieve this from the engine itself?

Here is an extremely useful guide on how you can call an API from unity: 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/c-programming/calling-restful-apis-unity3d/

I would highly recommend you do this API side as it safer than doing it through the engine, if that's what you are doing.

Comment: I used standard payment facebook API which uses my own server, and it worked well. but still I don't know how to make serverless payment with facebook API... I followed all of the things to do in the document but it seems don't work.

Comment: This may help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games_payments/payments_lite/   ....... Something called payment lite developed by facebook uses server-less payments. Hope this could be of use.